# Creating a wormhole connecting two universes that have different elementary particles?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics, wormholes, quantum

A civilization wishes to create a wormhole that connects two universes with different quantum fields from each other and different elementary particles to go with those different quantum fields.

On one side of the wormhole is a universe with the same particles as our universe, and on the other side is a universe, in which there are five types of charge that a particle can have.

- For the Dual charges "ordinary" fermions can have either a value of $\pm1$, and the force carriers for the Dual forces can have a Dual charge of $\pm2$, or $0$.  For the dual force, like charges repel and opposite charges attract.
- The three primary "colors" for the neo color charges are $Red$, $Green$, and blue denoted as $R$, $G$, and $B$, with $R+G+B=0$.  Also $x Red$, $x Green$,  or $x Blue$, is denoted as $xR$, $xG$, or $xB$.  "Ordinary" fermions can have a neo color charge of $R$, $G$, or $B$, or $0$, while the force carriers for the neo color forces can have a neo color charge of $R-G$, $R-B$, $G-B$, $G-R$, $B-R$, $B-G$, or $0$.  For the neo color charges like colors repel, with each of the three colors repelling themselves equally.
- The five primary tastes for the taste charges are $Sweet$, $Sour$, $Bitter$, $Salty$, and $Umami$ denoted as $W$, $O$, $B$, $A$, $U$, with $W+O+B+A+U=0$.  Also $x Sweet$, $x Sour$, $x Bitter$, $x Salty$, or $x Umami$ is denoted as $xW$, $xO$, $xB$, $xA$, or $xU$.  "Ordinary" fermions can have a taste charge of $W$, $O$, $B$, $A$, $U$, or $0$, and the force carriers for the taste forces can have any taste charge that allows them to change the taste charge of a taste charged "ordinary" fermion or they can have no taste charge.  For the taste charges like tastes repel, with all five tastes repelling themselves equally.
- The nine primary letters for the letter charges are $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$, $H$, $I$, with $A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I=0$.  "Ordinary" fermions can have a letter charge of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$, $H$, $I$ or $0$, and the force carriers for the letter force can have letter charge that allows them to change the letter charge of a letter charged "ordinary" fermion or they can have no letter charge.  For the letter charges like letters repel, with all nine letter repelling themselves equally.
- The three primary inks for the ink charge are $Cyan$, $Magenta$, and $Yellow$, denoted as $C$, $M$, $Y$, with $C+M+Y=0$.  Also $x Cyan$, $x Magenta$, or $x Yellow$, are denoted as $xC$, $xM$, or $xY$.  "Ordinary" fermions of $+1$ dual charge can have an ink charge of $C$, $M$, or $Y$, while "ordinary" fermions of $-1$ dual charge can have an ink charge of $-C$, $-M$, or $-Y$, and the force carrier for the ink force can have an ink charge of ${\pm}2C$, ${\pm}C{\pm}M$, ${\pm}C{\pm}Y$, ${\pm}2M$, ${\pm}M{\pm}Y$, or ${\pm}2Y$.

"Ordinary" fermions with an ink charge of $C$ or $-C$ can only interact with "ordinary" fermions with an ink charge of $M$ or $-M$, or $Y$ or $-Y$ through the ink force and Gravity, and "ordinary" fermions with an ink force of $M$ or $-M$ can only interact with "ordinary" fermions with an ink force of $Y$ or $-Y$ through the ink force and Gravity, as the dual charge is three separate types of charge that correspond to the $R$ and $-R$, $G$ and $-G$, and $B$ and $B$ ink charges, and the same is true for the neo color charge, the taste charge, and letter charge.

The type of dual charge, neo color charge, taste charge, or letter charge a particle has is independent of the values mentioned above.  The types and values of dual charge, neo color charge, taste charge, and letter charge that the force carrier of the ink force can have are such that when "ordinary" fermions interact through the ink force, the ink force must convert matter to anti-matter, and anti-matter to matter.

In order from least massive to most massive the force carriers are the force carrier for the letter forces, the force carriers for the taste forces, the force carriers for the neo color forces, and the force carriers for the dual forces, with the rank of the force carrier for the ink force unknown.  The mass of the force carrier for taste force is close to the mass of "ordinary" fermions that have all five types of charge.

Also when I say "ordinary" fermions I mean fermions that would be common in this universe even if they cannot exist in our own universe.

Assuming this type of wormhole could exist, would it be possible to travel through it without dying.

Comment: Please don't remove the [tag:hard-science] tag without the express consent of the OP, as doing so fundamentally changes the type of answers the question is asking for. For posterity, I feel it is best that OP is the one to make such a change, if they want to do it. We can disagree with the use of the hard-science requirement on any given question, and we can point out (as has both already been done) that it unnecessarily restricts the type of answers possible (and sometimes even whether an answer is possible at all), but it's still up to the OP to describe the type of answers that they want.

Comment: I added details to my question, and changed the tags.

Comment: Hello Anders.  Your recent edit put this question into the VTR queue.  I'm having trouble voting to reopen it because you're asking if a fictional construct (wormholes) can be used to connect to a fictional universe.  The answer is always "yes" due to [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).  Mathematically proving this to be theoretically possible is way, way, way beyond the scope of this site (and equally beyond the abilities of the average reader of your story).  Note that multiple questions makes the post too broad.

Comment: Come to think about it, I think you need to improve wording. For instance what is Charge B? You see... you say that Charge B can be Charge R, Charge G, or Charge B. I think you mean for the Force B the Charges are R, G and B. I could work with that, however I would side step most of the details of your description. Addendum: "ordinary" does not help much either.

Comment: Your recent edit added quite a lot of questions. Thus made the question too broad. Please narrow it down to one question per post.

Comment: @Theraot For Charge B, and also for charge E the R, G, and B stand for the values of Red, Green, and Blue and with $Red+Green+Blue=0$.  For charge C the W, O, B, A, U stand for Sweet, Sour, Bitter, Salty, and Umami, with $Sweet+Sour+Bitter+Salty+Umami=0$.  B Charge and E Charge would be both separate from the nuclear color charge of our universe and would be different charges from each other despite being described using the names of primary colors.  Also for C charge would be independent of our taste sense despite having the names of the five primary tastes.

Comment: @AndersGustafson I suppose, "ordinary" means "not standard model". Great, now, let us pretent the language is not confusing when Charge B can have a Charge of B. Would you please edit clarifications in the question? Beside, I would still side step all that in an answer because it is not clear how they would interact with the standard model. To be honest, if you had that figured out, one one hand you would not be asking and the other the question would be too specific. Instead I would answer with what would be required for it work... at least, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Theraot, I edited the details, changing the names of some of the colors and forces to make them less confusing, adding some details about them, and defining what I mean by "ordinary"